# how to clear an UART interrupt flag manually?

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, c, atmel

I'm using an  ATmega32. I have ISR(USART_RXC_vect) as follows

```
ISR(USART_RXC_vect)
{
    char ReceivedChar ;     
    ReceivedChar = UDR; // Fetch the received byte value into the variable "ReceivedChar"

    if(ReceivedChar == '\n'){       
        RxBuffer[RxPos] = '\0' ;                    
        RxReady=0;
        USART_Cmd_Eval();            
    }
    else{
        RxBuffer[RxPos] = ReceivedChar;
        RxPos++; 
    }
}
```

After triggering the ISR, it calls the following function to define which command is received from the PC.

```
void USART_Cmd_Eval(void)
{
            strcpy(RxCommand,RxBuffer);

            if(strcmp(RxCommand, "c") == 0){
                    RxReady = 1;                     
                    ADC_measure();
            }   
}
```

For each command, the relative function will be called. Like following:

```
void ADC_measure(void)
{
        while(RxReady ==1)
        {
                _delay_ms(50);
                // Measrung ADC values and send them to USART
        }
}
```

The problem is: I can't send another command because it is stuck in the ADC_measure function. Basically, it doesn't want to receive another command though ISR, I think it will continue open. Therefore, I think I should clear the interrupt flag before calling ADC_measure. Right? How can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When any interrupt routine is executed then *I* bit of *SREG* is cleared to avoid next interrupt execution. The bit is reset by *RETI*. I.e. you can do it also manually *SBI SREG,I*  (or via *uint8_t sreg = SREG; sreg |= _BV(I); SREG = sreg;*).

But also *USART_RXC_vect* may be called again! I don't like any *_delay()* in interrupt routines as it must be as short as possible. You should recode it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. My goal is to let USART_RXC to be called again while executing adc_meassure function. Besides, which delay should be removed ??

Comment: *USART_RXC_vect->USART_Cmd_Eval->ADC_measure->_delay_ms()* and there is even long *while* loop in *ADC_measure* function.

Comment: oh,, you have right. Do you have another solution for that ? i mean where can i execute the while loop after closing the USART_RXC and USART_Cmd_Eval ?

Comment: I would do in main program loop (if you are using Arduino it's *loop()*). Just to look *RxReady* flag, declare as volatile and add some anti-race-condition stuff.